# How i can write value btag to another resource in Local Storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

For example,this my resource :

http://lands.dev/ml/sport-email/de/01-ronaldo/index.min.html?btag=a_1064b_333c_

On this web page i have a link, after click we redirect to another web page.
How can i read this `value 'btag=a_1064b_333c_'` from my url and write to Local Storage another resource after clicking.
Thank you so much for help.

Comment: your description is vague

Comment: I have site.On this site I have a link.After click this link,i will redirect to another site. In url of my site,I have value of my btag=a_1064b_333c_ I need to write this value 'btag = a_1064b_333c_' in Local Storage to another web page after redirect

Answer (score 0):

The **URLSearchParams** interface defines utility methods to work with the query string of a URL.

Example:

```
var paramsString = "btag=a_1064b_333c_"
var searchParams = new URLSearchParams(paramsString);

//Iterate the search parameters.
for (let p of searchParams) {
  console.log(p);
}

searchParams.has("btag") === true; // true
searchParams.get("btag") === "a_1064b_333c_"; // true
searchParams.getAll("btag"); // ["a_1064b_333c_"]
```

It's pretty new but it is a part of ES standard and very simple.

Polyfill:
https://github.com/WebReflection/url-search-params

Comment: Okay,Thank you,I have this value.

But how i can write this '["a_1064b_333c_"]' after click for link to another web page.

After click button,I do this
window.location = 'http://malina.soft2bet.com/' + lang + '/?email=' + value + searchParams.getAll("btag") +  '#popup-reg'  
but it's not working.


How i can write value of my btag to Local Storage on web page,which stay in window.location?

Comment: locaStorage.setItem("btag", searchParams.get("btag"))

Comment: Okay,My link will be :
 window.location = 'malina.soft2bet.com/'; + lang + '/?email=' + value + localStorage.setItem("btag", searchParams.get("btag")) + '#popup-reg', like this?
It's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this javascript code.

```
var urlPart = window.location.search.substr(1);
var val = urlPart.split("=")[1];
window.localStorage.setItem('btag', val);
```

Comment: This code will write value of my btag in Local Storage of web page where i am.
I need write this value to another web page after redirect.
For example,I click button on my web page,for example this my resource:
http://lands.dev/ml/sport-email/de/01-ronaldo/index.min.html?btag=a_1064b_333c_
After click button i will go on this web page:
 window.location = 'http://malina.soft2bet.com/' + lang + '/?email=' + value + '#popup-reg';
And i need to write value of my btag in Local Storage of this resource : 'http://malina.soft2bet.com/' + lang + '/?email=' + value + '#popup-reg';

Comment: I have site.On this site I have a link.After click this link,i will redirect to another site.
In url of my site,I have value of my btag=a_1064b_333c_
I need to write this value 'btag = a_1064b_333c_' in Local Storage to another web page after redirect.